# Is there an FTP interface for Windows Explorer which uses "incoming" and "outgoing" folders?

Tags: windows-explorer, ftp

I'm trying to support someone with queries about an old FTP server we have. On the server we have a directory specifically set aside, and various files are both read from and written to this directory.

This FTP server was set up before my time, and has been running fine for years, but there is no documentation beyond the code and config on the server itself.

The person at the other end has recently been replaced by someone new. I am guessing there has not been much documentation or handover at their end either.

The new person is claiming that they can see files in the "outgoing" folder, but cannot see files in the "incoming" folder. I replied that there is no "incoming" or "outgoing" - there's just one folder.

The reply was this screenshot ....

[image: incoming_outgoing]

I don't know where to go from here. If I ping the server named in the screenshot, it's not the IP of the FTP server I am operating from, although there could be proxies, firewalls ... I'm not normally the network guy either.

It would help me, if I knew what kind of set up this person is using. I'm not familiar with Windows to this degree. Is the "incoming" and "outgoing" folder something normal for an FTP interface via Windows Explorer? Does it have a name? Or where could I lookup more about it?

Comment: This is unlikely anything specific to Windows File Explorer. Those seems to be just two folders on the FTP. And any other FTP client would show them the same way. Well, you can ask them to try other client.